# Does $\sum |a_n|b_n $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Let $$\sum |a_n|<\infty,\quad \sum b_n<\infty$$

Then

$$\sum |a_n|b_n < \infty?$$

---

I tried to bound this sum, since $0 < a_n < 1 $ for $\forall n>N$
but this wasn't efficient because $b_n$ isn't a positive sequence.

Next, I tried to use AM-GM but I don't have $\sum (b_n)^2<\infty$ so I guess I need another approach to prove / disprove this one.

Thanks for help

Comment: [Relevant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376463/when-multiply-absolutely-convergent-seires-and-conditionally-convergent-series/376468#376468), even it is nearly off topic there.

Comment: Have already checked for duplicates?

Comment: Apparently you write $\sum b_n <\infty$ for convergence of $\sum b_n$. This is not correct. Does $\sum (-1)$ converge?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes I think it has been used as a symbol but it is misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We simply have that eventually $|b_n|<1$ and then $\sum |a_n|b_n$ converges absolutely by direct comparison test with $\sum |a_n|$.